# Drupal Forum - Users unable to post correctly

Tags: nodes

I am using drupal 6.  The forum (core-optional module) I am using contains 3 containers.  Where I run into an issue, is that the authenticated users are unable to post their forum topic into one of the containers.  The drop down box listing the 3 containers does not appear.  If they select the container from the main page of the forum and choose "New Topic", they can submit a topic, but their topic will not appear on the forum, till the admin goes in and edits their post and assign it to the correct container.  The admin is able to post correctly with out issues.  I attached a picture of the admin screen and user screen.  How do I get the users to post correctly?  Thank you in advance.[image]